# Rewrite all URLs within subdirectory to index.html so JavaScript can use the path

Tags: htaccess, apache, javascript, apache2

I have a part of domain `example.com/~mypart`. In that folder is *index.html*. If I visit `example.com/~mypart/something` I get a "Not Found" error.

I want every address with some string after `example.com/~mypart/` to rewrite to `example.com/~mypart` (*index.html*) and keep the string so I can use JavaScript in *index.html* to get that string.

Comment: I changed "redirect" to "rewrite".   Redirects change the URL but rewrites don't.   You say you want to give access to the URL to JavaScript, so you will need a rewrite that doesn't change the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard *front-controller* pattern. You can use mod_dir's `FallbackResource` directive in the `.htaccess` file at `/~mypart/.htaccess`. For example:

```
FallbackResource /~mypart/index.html
```

(If `/~mypart` is an [Apache per-user web directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html) then just use `/index.html`.)

Many examples will use mod_rewrite, but unless you have more complex URL rewriting requirements, then the above is sufficient (and recommended).

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Comment: Oh I was looking for answers for about an hour and I did not find anything that used FallbackResource. Very nice!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Just curious, is `/~mypart` a physical subdirectory on your filesystem, or an "Apache per-user web directory" (as mentioned above)?

Comment: Apache per-user web directory

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `httaccess` file:

```
    # if folder does not exist
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # if file does not exist
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # redirect anything to
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ~mypart/$1 [L]
```

[credit where is due](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432700/capturing-and-preserving-uri-on-redirect-on-apache-php-server-without-404-header)

And after that, once the page loads, you can use the following javascript code to get the requested file

```
    var requestedResource = window.location.href.replace('example.com/~mypart/','');
```

Comment: Thank you, however it doesn't work for me. Probably I am doing something wrong. But it's okay because solution from MrWhite did work for me and you showed me side of htaccess which I did not know about.  So thank you.

Comment: There are a few issues with these directvies... **1.** If using mod_rewrite, you need to enable the rewrite engine, ie. `RewriteEngine On`. **2.** In order to only target the `/~mypart` subdirectory, these directives would need to go in the `/~mypart/.htaccess` file (as opposed to the document root), although `/~mypart` does "look-like" an Apache web-user directory, so this may not be necessary. **3.** Either way, you would need to also remove the `~mypart/` from the `RewriteRule` _substitution_. **4.** This currently rewrites to itself (`$1` backreference), this should be `index.html`.